# failed editing php mysqli CRUD - failed in updating data mysql only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, edit

i have this code, but failed to execute, please help me out this problem

the connection

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pwd";
$database = "cece";

// Create connection
$terhubung = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password, $database);

// Check Connection
if  ($terhubung->connect_error) {
    die ("connection failed: " . $terhubung->connect_error); 
}
?>
```

this is the editing form

```
<?php 
                    include "conn.php";
                    $id = $_GET['no'];
                    $query_mysql = $terhubung->query("SELECT * FROM data222 WHERE id='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
                    $nomor = 1;
                    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_mysql)){
                    ?>
                <form action="edit/edit_data222.php" method="post" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">ID</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" name="id" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $data['id']?>" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >Nama PT</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="text" name="nama_pt" value="<?php echo $data['nama_pt']?>" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Barang</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                      <select name="brg" class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1">

                        <option value="">Pilih...</option>
                        <option value="I" <?php if($data['brg'] == 'I'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >I</option>
                        <option value="E" <?php if($data['brg'] == 'E'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >E</option>
                        <option value="C" <?php if($data['brg'] == 'C'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >C</option>

                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>     



                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Tipe</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                      <select name="jalur" class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1">
                        <option value="">Jalur...</option>
                        <option value="HL" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'HL'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >HL</option>
                        <option value="HM" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'HM'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >HM</option>
                        <option value="HH" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'HH'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >HH</option>
                        <option value="KL" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'KL'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >KL</option>
                        <option value="KM" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'KM'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >KM</option>
                        <option value="KH" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'KH'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >KH</option>
                        <option value="ML" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'ML'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >ML</option>
                        <option value="MM" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'MM'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >MM</option>
                        <option value="MH" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'MH'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >MH</option>
                        <option value="MK" <?php if($data['jalur'] == 'MK'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >MK</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >No doc</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="text" name="no_dok" value="<?php echo $data['no_dok']?>" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                      <input id="tglx1" name="tgl_dok" class="date-picker form-control has-feedback-left" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['tgl_dok']?>">
                      <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>                      
                  </div> 

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >No Surat</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="text" name="no_print" value="<?php echo $data['no_print']?>" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                      <input id="tglx2" name="tgl_print" class="date-picker form-control has-feedback-left" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['tgl_print']?>">
                      <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>                      
                  </div> 

                  <!--ssssssss-->

                  <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <?php } ?>
```

this is the update code

```
<?php 

include 'conn.php';

$id=$_POST['id'];
$nama_pt=$_POST['nama_pt'];
$brg=$_POST['brg'];
$jalur=$_POST['jalur'];
$no_dok=$_POST['no_dok'];
$tgl_dok=$_POST['tgl_dok'];
$no_print=$_POST['no_print'];
$tgl_print=$_POST['tgl_print'];

mysqli_query($terhubung, "UPDATE data222 SET 
id='$id',
nama_pt='$nama_pt',
brg='$brg',
jalur='$jalur',
no_dok='$no_dok',
tgl_dok='$tgl_dok',
no_print='$no_print',
tgl_print='$tgl_print',
WHERE id ='$id'
");
?>
```

when i clicked submit, there was no change in mysql. what is the mistake

Comment: Even if your code runs properly, it is also dangerous, it is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Please give more information when implementing the code

Comment: How many you have form on file edit?

Comment: the code didnt work. i use the similar but it runs. how do i do. i use local connection only.

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: there is no error notification, i use putty

Comment: is any other tool like putty to analyze the network access ?

Comment: you can insstall "XAMPP" in your computer and run as localhost

Comment: i instal xampp as localhost in my laptop to do the code, but my server, i use linux. i use php 7 altogether

Comment: yes, first You try to run it well in your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

try if will work change this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success" />
```

and change the update code

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
copy paste the code you write in update
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try Edit put variable in `{}` with query